# Implementing a audio visualizer in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, math, audio

I wish to implement a audio visualizer widget (similar to what Winamp has) in WPF. How would I approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two articles may be of use to you:

http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/3dhittesting.htm
http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/datavisualizationwpf.htm

They're two articles in a series of 3D visualization using WPF. They're a bit targeted on intro WPF usage. Here are a few more:

http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2009/01/30/data-visualization-toolkit-for-silverlight-descry/
[Beats per minute from real-time audio input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79445/beats-per-minute-from-real-time-audio-input)

In general, you'll want to do a bit of realtime analysis on the audio stream. Beat detection is an easy one - provide some sort of pulsing action that lines up with the beat, intensity increasing with volume, and so on.

Here's another fantastic article:
http://knol.google.com/k/music-visualization-techniques#

And another similar question from StackOverflow:
[Creating music visualizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153712/creating-music-visualizer)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to spend too long implementing the whole solution around this, I'd recommend you check out [NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio).  It has audio capture and playback, along with a good amount of visualisation stuff OOTB.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but thanks for the NAudio link. I've been looking for a .net mp3 playback library for ages.