# How to create an audio frequency visualizer

Tags: audio, colors, frequency-analysis

I have a fun artistic project in mind :) Basically, I would like to load a music file (probably as a .wav), and take it up multiple octaves so that you can represent it on the color spectrum. My question is, how do I go about breaking down an audio file so that I can perform this transformation? I'm curious to see if colors can enhance the experience of listening to music if both are "in harmony" :)

All the best!
Anthony :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148008/music-visualization/3149481#3149481

Comment: @fdcpp yup that's exactly it! Thanks!! I was doing some more digging and found out someone already did the exact thing I'm trying to do with colors back in 2003 lol. Here's their github :) It has a couple bugs that I'm trying to figure out, but it's pretty much ready to go! https://github.com/rho-bit/Psynesthesia

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I found a thread that pretty much answers my question! [Trying to get the frequencies of a .wav file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612204/trying-to-get-the-frequencies-of-a-wav-file-in-python) Basically I can multiply the calculated frequency by 2^x to represent it with light :) Thanks for all the help!

Edit: While I was working on finishing up my program I stumbled upon this https://github.com/rho-bit/Psynesthesia. Looks like someone did exactly what I was trying to do back in 2003!! This was my first post and I totally love this website. Look forward to using it more! :)